# SQL Objects API - Get all columns?

Tags: jdbi

I am using the SQL objects API in the following lines of code in my data access object to get the name field from a row in an SQL table where the ID matches the one provided.

```
@SqlQuery("select name from users where id = :id")
String findNameById(@Bind("id") int id);
```

That works all well and good, but what on earth do I do if I want to return all of the fields for that row in the table, not just the name, but all colums for that record?

I did try using :

```
"select * from users where id = :id"
```

But that isn't right, it only seemed to return the id field (possibly as it is the first column in the table, and my method returns a string?)

Anyhow, I am all out of ideas on this and would appreciate all the help I can get.

---

Additional Info as I get requests for information :

This is the method signature of my method in the controller that calls my dao.

```
public String retrieveUserRecord(@PathParam("id") int id)
```

As you can see, it returns a string, as does the findNameByID method in the dao...

What I want to do, is pass the id using my method signature, and get back all of my columns as one nice JSON object if possible?

Comment: Can you add your method signature ?

Comment: Added the signature :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return type should not be string when you want to get all the fields. I am assuming you have 'USER' model like this.

```
  public class User {
     private Integer id;
     private String name;

    public User(id, name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
   }
  }
```

There are some ways to map DB result to Java model. You should create mapper for class user.

```
 public class UserMapper<User>  implements ResultSetMapper<User> {
         public User map(int row, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException { 
         return new User(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name") );
         }
}
```

You should mention this mapper in sqlObject api.

```
@SqlQuery("select * from users where id = :id")
@Mapper(UserMapper.class)
String retrieveUserRecord(@Bind("id") int id);
```

You can also use MapResultAsBean if you have setters & getters in the model.

You can also use [this library](http://manikandan-k.github.io/jdbi_folder/).

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late upvote and setting your answer to best. I was actually busy getting it to work, your answer pretty much nailed it! 

For future readers with the same problem, I only had to change one thing here - Instead of using "getInteger()" I used "getInt()".

THANKS! :)